# How to Disable Button When DropDown Is Empty in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to keep a button disabled until user chooses one of the options from the dropdown.  Once they do the button becomes enabled.  This is what I have now...

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="rejectionReason">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select> 
<button type="button" [disabled]="rejectionReason.length > 0">Submit</button>
```

I've also tried

```
[disabled]="rejectionReason === ''"
```

without any luck.  Any thoughts on the proper way to do this in Angular 2+?

Comment: Besides determining its length to enable/disable the submit button, what are you using `rejectionReason` for? I've provided a very similar solution, but without using two-way binding.

Comment: Can you post your typescript code because we have no idea what is happening behind the scenes with ```rejectionReason```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not assigning any value to the `rejectionReason`, to assign the selected value to the the `rejectionReason` you need to define the `value` attribute in the `option` in the attribute tag. Now there are 2 ways you can do it. If you want the values predefined/hardcoded you can simply use.

```
<option value="one">One</option>
```

else if you want to give options from a variable, assuming `exampleVarString` is defined in your component class and can be `stringified`,

```
<option [value]="exampleVarString">One</option>
```

you can either use `[value]` attribute like above, it only supports `strings` by the way. Or you can use `[ngValue]="exampleVarObject"`.

Also for your case I use strings as options.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="rejectionReason">
   <!-- Notice I have used empty string for the select option,
        which makes sense to me while disabled checking -->
   <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<!-- Since empty strings are "falsey",you can 
     use ! directly on the rejection reason.  -->
<button type="button" [disabled]="!rejectionReason">Submit</button>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bh3repkcaY0RuZmqWiSZ?p=preview) is the working plunk, I also included am example of `ngFor`.

Answer (score -1):

you do not have a [value] to the options.So rejectReason.length will always be zero.So Instead try below:

```
     <select [(ngModel)]="rejectionReason">
                    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled>Select</option>
                    <option [value]="one">One</option>
                    <option [value]="Two">Two</option>
                    <option [value]="Three">Three</option>
               </select> 


<button type="button" [disabled]="rejectionReason.length > 0">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is that the button never becomes enabled, it's because in order for disabled not to be set, the value of the attribute has to be null, not false....

```
rejectionReason.length > 0 || null
```